# jQuery click eventhandler issues

Tags: jquery

I've build a site that has accordion sections that expand whenever someone clicks on the header section for that page, the click handler is placed on

```
$('.section h2').click
```

However, when a user is logged in as admin, there are 'EDIT' links applied to the header, so I only want the section to expand if the area clicked is not "a.edit-link".

I've tried things like `$('.section h2:not(a.edit-link)').click`... or `$('.section h2').not('a.edit-link').click`, but niether of these options are working for me..

Am I missing out on something obvious?

Comment: The edit link is contained within the <h2> tags?  Can you post sample code so I understand your html layout better.

Comment: some HTML code will help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), like this:

```
$('.section h2').click(function() {
  //do stuff
});
$('.section h2 a.edit-link').click(function(e) { 
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

When a click on an `a.edit-link` happens, that click just won't bubble up to the `<h2>` parent, and its [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler won't fire.

Alternatively you could check the event target inside your handler, like this:

```
$('.section h2').click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).hasClass('edit-link')) return; //bomb out
  //do stuff
});
```

Comment: @Conor - Welcome :) Be sure to accept answers on this and future questions via the check-mark beside the one that resolve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this personally, but here is a thought:

- give the admin links their own css class
- after adding the click handler for the header add a more specific click handler for the edit links that does not expand the the section
- make sure event bubbling is suppressed on the link handlers